# Can I add a link to my ORCID Id in the statement of purpose?

Tags: phd, statement-of-purpose

Is it a good practice to add a link to the orcid ID in the statement of purpose for a PhD admission application?

Also can I add a link to my published paper? Can I include an abstract as well.

Comment: ORCID is just an identifier used to tell if two people are the same person or not.  In your application there is only one applicant, so there is no purpose for an ORCID.

Answer (score 4):

Your ORCID would be better off placed on your CV, either next to or below your name. You can certainly cite your published paper in your statement of purpose, if it is relevant to the work you want to pursue in your PhD. You should also list your publications on your CV. It might be worth looking at the websites of a few professors in your field, to find examples of how they structure and format their CVs.